# Some marker types don't display in Plotly-Dash scatter plot

Tags: plotly

I'm trying to use a custom marker type in a **plotly dash app**. I'm defining my graph as below:

```
html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(
            figure=dict(
                data=[
                    dict(
                        x=[5, 10, 20, 15],
                        y=[1, 2, 1, 3],
                        type='scatter',
                        mode='markers',
                        marker=dict(
                            color='Red',
                            symbol='line-ns',
                            size=20,
                            opacity=1,
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
                layout=dict(),
            ),
            id='my-graph',
        ),
    ],
),
```

When I use `symbol='square'` it works as shown on the left below, but when `symbol='line-ns'` the hover works, but the symbol is invisible.

[image]
[image]

The basic symbols seem to work, but most of the less common symbols seem to have this problem.

Looking at the documentation here:

https://plotly.com/python/marker-style/#custom-marker-symbols

I have an example in a notebook where `symbol='line-ns'` does work using the graph objects:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Generate example data
import numpy as np

# Build figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add trace with large markers
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='markers',
        x=[2, 2],
        y=[4.25, 4.75],
        marker=dict(
            symbol='line-ns',
            color='rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
            size=40,
            line=dict(
                color='MediumPurple',
                width=8
            )
        ),
        showlegend=False
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the same issue. It seems the shapes that have no filling are not displayed: shapes 33 to 45 (`cross_thin` to `line_nw`). The other ones can be displayed normally.

I could solve it by specifying the `line_width` parameter for the markers.

```
marker=dict(symbol='line-ns',
            line_width=2)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and haven't found any solution yet. However `symbol='line-ns-open'` works for me with a somehow similar result.

Comment: This one is nice as it works with color groups in Plotly express

Answer (score 0):

The same is for `color`, which implies that `line = dict(color, width)` does not work inside `marker = dict()` and it is necessary to use `line_color` and `line_width` instead ... maybe other `line` attributes are being affected too.

Comment: Since this isn't an answer to the question, rather it's useful additional detail about the issue, I would encourage you to re-post it as a comment under the question rather than as an answer. That's the accepted convention on stackoverflow.